# sorting a json list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

```
 var myData = [
                  {"Identifier":1,"Naam":"Van Der Valk","Adres":"Europaweg 218","Postcode":"1238AC","Plaats":"Zoetermeer","Longitude":"4.48822","Latitude":"52.06258", "Status":"Laadpunten Beschikbaar", "lunch":"true", "diner":"true", "meet":"true", "wifi":"true", "Distance": "10.1"},
                  {"Identifier":2,"Naam":"Meram place","Adres":"NOT Given 1","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Rotterdam","Longitude":"4.48178","Latitude":"51.92422", "lunch":"false", "Distance": "181"},
                  {"Identifier":3,"Naam":"Station Zwolle","Adres":"NOT Given 6","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Zwolle","Longitude":"6.08302","Latitude":"52.51677", "lunch":"false", "Distance": "5.1"},
                  {"Identifier":4,"Naam":"Pompstation Shell","Adres":"NOT Given 1","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Den Haag","Longitude":"4.30070","Latitude":"52.07050", "lunch":"false"},
                  {"Identifier":5,"Naam":"Amsterdam Arena","Adres":"NOT Given 218","Postcode":"0000LL","Plaats":"Amsterdam","Longitude":"4.89517","Latitude":"52.37022", "lunch":"true", "diner":"true", "wifi":"true", "meet":"true", "Distance": "34.2"}
                  ];
```

I have a question, given I have the above json.. and i want to append this to a list i.e ul li.. how is it possible to get the list ordered with the one with the lowest distance etc.

Comment: Ordered by what? List formatted how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not JSON. It's already a JavaScript Array of Objects, so you'd just use `.sort()`.

```
myData.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (+a.Distance || 0) - (+b.Distance || 0);
});
```

Note that I'm substituting `0` if the numeric conversion of `.Distance` failed.

Please read the MDN docs for [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to learn more about sorting JavaScript Arrays.

---

To create elements, you can loop the sorted array using the `$.each()` iterator.

```
var list = $("#mylist");

$.each(myData, function(i, obj) {
    $("<li>", {
         text: obj.Naam + ": Distance - " + obj.Distance
    }).appendTo(list);
});
```